# New to iOS trying to pass variable to NSString for search function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to include a search option in my app. I want it to search for a new item once the search button is pressed. I have a static **http** address and simply need to add my search terms after the final "/" in the address from a text box in the app.

Here is my method in my searchClass.m:

```
- (NSString *)getGameData:(NSString *)gameToSearch {
    searchAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxx.com/json/%@", gameToSearch];

    return  searchAddress;
}
```

(searchAddress is defined as an NSString in my header file)

Here is from my main viewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)searchGameInfo {
    searchClass *dataTest = [[searchClass alloc] init];
    NSString *test = [dataTest getGameData:searchGame.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", test);
}
```

The app compiles fine, but the app crashes with

> [searchClass getSearchData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Search your code for a call to `getSearchData:`. It appears that it should be `getGameData:`.

Comment: Can you show me your searchClass, App crashes because it doesn't able to get your method searchGameInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error seems like your **searchClass** has not any method with name **getSearchData** so this types of error is occur.
Please put relevant code and also how you are calling this **getSearchData** method ?

**EDITE:**

Try with following step in

1) In **searchClass.h** define method `-(NSString *)getGameData:(NSString *)gameToSearch;`
2) In **searchClass.m** define body of method;
3) Add **#import searchClass.h** in you **viewController.m** file
4) Create object of  **searchClass** such like

```
searchClass *obj = [[searchClass alloc] init];
```

and Now call this method by

```
 [obj getGameData:@"SearchText"];
```

Hope this is helpful in your case:

Comment: Thanks! Works now, for some reason, Xcode didn't recognize the method that I declared in my header file. Spits out a string now.